# Tabs data not showing in the Android but works fine in IOS?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-scrollable-tab-view

```
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
    
    <ScrollView style={styles.container} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

<ScrollableTabView
                style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: mt ? mt : 0 }}
                tabBarActiveTextColor="#53ac49"
                renderTabBar={(i) =>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        {i.tabs.map((item, index) => {
                            return <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                <TabTextStyle
                                    text={item.label}
                                    index={index}
                                    numberofTabs={tabs.length}
                                    onPress={(item_index) => i.goToPage(item_index)}
                                    selectedTab={i.activeTab == index ? true : false} />
                            </View>
                        })}
                    </View>
                }>
                {tabs.map(item => {
                    return item
                })}
            </ScrollableTabView>
```

I am using this and it is working fine in IOS but it is not showing data in android. I am able to find it why it happening so anybody can provide me detail for this. Not working in scrollview. But I need scrollview so what is the solution. Please let me know.